# grep out url from html files and pick top one somehow

Tags: awk, grep, html-parsing

I have a many (think 17,000) html files that contain links. Each html file can contain many links but they all reference the same video mp4 but in different resolutions. I want to grep out only the link that is the highest resolution, ie. if there is a reference to 720, 1080, or 1440, I want the link for the 1440 and not bother with the others. The maximum resolution varies though, so I cannot just hard code the 1440 (the max resolution in one html file might be 720, in another 1440 for example).

The html files content are between 2k and 80k each and have repeated content that has this sort of structure, sometimes in one line, sometimes spanning multiple lines

```
{"url":"https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01", 
uploadedBy="fdb778f8-c347-4c28-90f4-d8be4b4a20f0", 
 owner="3ba62dba-8fb1-468d-8349-2e42a5330785",video="1024p", 
   group="a4307f09-4804-4802-9ba4-8e8eaf3d3439"},
   {"url":"https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446384.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01", 
 uploadedBy="fdb778f8-c347-4c28-90f4-d8be4b4a20f0", 
       owner="3ba62dba-8fb1-468d-8349-2e42a5330785",
    video="720p", group="a4307f09-4804-4802-9ba4-8e8eaf3d3439"}
```

What I want from grep is just

https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01

AND NOT (as this is the lower resolution, the highest resolution in the single file i 1024, the lower one 720)

https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446384.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01

I just cannot get to a solution, using grep -oh and '\"url\":\"https://localhost[^"]*

I think what I need to do it get all urls, and the video=, sort by url, then video highest to lowest, and take the top one, but ..... I have no idea and am now just fumbling trying anything I can find on Google and changing it.

Can anyone help?

Oh, the mp4 always appears before the video quality

I am using Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:49:07 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 2):

Using standard UNIX tools including any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    while ( match($0,/("url":|[[:alpha:]]+=)"[^"]+"/) ) {
        tag = val = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        sub(/[:=].*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^:=]*[:=]/,"",val)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",tag)
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
        if ( tag == "video" ) {
            print f["video"], f["url"]
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1024p   https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
720p    https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446384.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -n
720p    https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446384.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
1024p   https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -rn
1024p   https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
720p    https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446384.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -rn | head -1
1024p   https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2
https://localhost/676/hg66333/56354446353.mp4?user=893668f5-8fab-4916-9697-f45aee61aa01
```

All it's relying on is that any given tag=value string isn't itself split across lines and that they all follow the format you showed in your question.

Comment: This is an extremely generic solution. Thanks to the while loop, this will handle any file. Inclusive files with only a single line with a multitude of entries. This is a very nice solution.

Comment: @Steve did this solve your problem? Do you have any questions about it?